# Facebook UI control shared data

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

On our page we implemented facebook sharing with the help of the Facebook API.

We simply display the feed dialog like this:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',//'share',//
    display: 'iframe',
    link: siteUrl,
    href: siteUrl,
    picture: imgUrl,
    name: title,
    caption: caption,
    description: text
};

FB.ui(obj, function(response){
  console.log(response);
});
```

When I click on the share button, the popup, that comes up, displays the data just fine. But when I share it, the website data is displayed.

We can't use open graph meta tags, since the site is a promotional competition where users enter the competition and other users vote and share the data on Facebook. The Entries don't have their own page.

It's especially strange since I know sharing data like this was possible when I last worked with the Facebook API.

Does anyone why we can't control the shared data?

Comment: AFAIK Facebook is doing some U/X testing, and is redirecting some users from the Feed to the Share dialog – and the latter doesn’t support those parameters. // You’re “we _can’t_ use open graph meta tags” might actually rather be a we’re not willing/too lazy to, am I right? _“The Entries don't have their own page”_ – well then see to it that they _get_ one. It doesn’t have to be a full “page”, it is enough when an individual URL returns the meta data to the FB scraper. Human visitors you can redirect elsewhere, either via JS, or server-side (that’ll need an exception for the FB scraper then.)

Comment: Honestly, we can't :), a while back our customer wanted to add a contest to his site. Only problem was, it wasn't a standard contest and the weren't able to implement it on the site in the provided timeframe. So we improvised, made a separate page, hosted it on another server and embedded it bia iframe ( I know, I didn't like the solution either, but shipping beats perfection). A few days back we got a request to make a simmilar contest. The link has to point to the main site, while the information has to come from the contest page. But I like your thinking, I guess we can redirect via js :)